# Replace local characters and compare it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, compare

I want to show all `.item` which first letter is equal to a variable.

Problem - if the first letter is a local character and I'm trying to replace them - `č-ć-đ-š-ž` replace with `c-c-d-s-z` respectively.

I'm expecting item `Ćao` (for example) becomes visible after this code but it doesn't work.

```
var a = 'c';
$('.item').each(function(){
    var b = $(this).text().charAt(0);
    var mapObj = {č:"c", ć:"c", đ:"d", š:"s", ž:"z"};
    b = b.replace(/č|ć|đ|š|ž/i, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
    if (b == a) {$(this).show();}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add `.toLowerCase()` to where your `mapObj` item is returned:

```js
var a = 'c';
$('.item').each(function() {
  var b = $(this).text().charAt(0);
  var mapObj = {
    č: "c",
    ć: "c",
    đ: "d",
    š: "s",
    ž: "z"
  };
  b = b.replace(/č|ć|đ|š|ž/i, function(matched) {
    return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()]; // map to lowercase char
  });
  if (b.toLowerCase() == a.toLowerCase()) { // always compare like cases
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">Ćao</div>
```

Even though your match is insensitive, it does not automatically convert the characters returned.

Comment: `/i` should means insensitive, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Even though your match is insensitive, it does not automatically convert the characters returned.

Comment: Thanks, but what if variable `a` is a capital letter ? Is there a way to make all this procedure case insenstive ?

Comment: You'll want to either convert all characters to uppercase or all to lowercase when doing comparisons (see edit)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Capital `Ć` and lower-case `ć` are two completely different characters. You'll need to expand your mapping table accordingly.

Comment: `/i` should means insensitive, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @bonaca Yes, but the actual matched character is returned, not the one in the regex.